# Is it better to Cast and object or use dynamic during databinding

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, dynamic, casting

I guess I am curious what is better?
Casting the DataItem to the type i know it is...
Or
pass the object to a function that expects a Dynamic, and let the DLR do its magic.

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div>
        <%# FormatBlogLink(Container.DataItem) %>
        OR
        <%# FormatBlogLink((BlogPost)Container.DataItem) %>
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

Code

```
protected string FormatBlogLink(dynamic blogPost)
{
/// Do a bunch of stuff 
}
```

vs:

```
protected string FormatBlogLink(BlogPost blogPost)
{
/// Do a bunch of stuff 
}
```

My example is simple, 
I thought i read that the DLR will cache things it looked at so it, 
so I am curious, what is worst for larger data sources... lots of casting or lots of using dynamic? 
(or) am i a bit crazy ... :)

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion would be to cast to the appropriate type, if that is what you are expecting to use. The only reason to use `dynamic` in your `FormatBlogLink` is if you expect to pass different objects that just happen to share the same property names and methods, etc. Otherwise, cast to the appropriate type and benefit from intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

I too would opt for the cast - but you can do this in your FromatBlockLink - method (let it take object). This has the advantage that you remove this (little) logic from your view and of course you can check the type in your function.

```
protected string FormatBlogLink(object blogPost)
{
   var post = blogPost as BlogPost;
   if (post == null) 
   {
      // throw or use show error-message
   }
   /// Do a bunch of stuff 
}
```